# Ogre g++ compile-time error

Tags: c++, g++, ogre

On ubuntu, I have compiled and installed all the ogre libraries. However, when I try to compile a tutorial with this command

```
g++ -o otest ogre.cpp -I `pkg-config --libs --cflags OGRE OIS` -lOgreMain -lOI
```

and it outputs

```
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o: In function `TutorialApplication::TutorialApplication()':
ogre.cpp:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::BaseApplication()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o: In function `TutorialApplication::TutorialApplication()':
ogre.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::BaseApplication()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o: In function `TutorialApplication::~TutorialApplication()':
ogre.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::~BaseApplication()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o: In function `TutorialApplication::~TutorialApplication()':
ogre.cpp:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::~BaseApplication()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o: In function `TutorialApplication::~TutorialApplication()':
ogre.cpp:(.text+0x1ae): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::~BaseApplication()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o: In function `main':
ogre.cpp:(.text+0x44d): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::go()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0xc): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::frameRenderingQueued(Ogre::FrameEvent const&)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x1c): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::go()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x20): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::setup()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x24): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::configure()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x28): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::chooseSceneManager()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x2c): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::createCamera()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x30): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::createFrameListener()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x38): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::destroyScene()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x3c): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::createViewports()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x40): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::setupResources()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x44): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::createResourceListener()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x48): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::loadResources()'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x4c): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::keyPressed(OIS::KeyEvent const&)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x50): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::keyReleased(OIS::KeyEvent const&)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x54): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::mouseMoved(OIS::MouseEvent const&)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x58): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::mousePressed(OIS::MouseEvent const&, OIS::MouseButtonID)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x5c): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::mouseReleased(OIS::MouseEvent const&, OIS::MouseButtonID)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x60): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::windowResized(Ogre::RenderWindow*)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x64): undefined reference to `BaseApplication::windowClosed(Ogre::RenderWindow*)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x7c): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to BaseApplication::windowResized(Ogre::RenderWindow*)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x84): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to BaseApplication::windowClosed(Ogre::RenderWindow*)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0x9c): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to BaseApplication::keyPressed(OIS::KeyEvent const&)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0xa0): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to BaseApplication::keyReleased(OIS::KeyEvent const&)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0xb4): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to BaseApplication::mouseMoved(OIS::MouseEvent const&)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0xb8): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to BaseApplication::mousePressed(OIS::MouseEvent const&, OIS::MouseButtonID)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTV19TutorialApplication[vtable for TutorialApplication]+0xbc): undefined reference to `non-virtual thunk to BaseApplication::mouseReleased(OIS::MouseEvent const&, OIS::MouseButtonID)'
/tmp/cc9ndjXQ.o:(.rodata._ZTI19TutorialApplication[typeinfo for TutorialApplication]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for BaseApplication'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anyone know how to fix this/what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a compile time error, it's a link time error.

By the looks of things, you probably aren't compiling all the `*.cpp` files. What file is the body of `TutorialApplication`'s constructor in? You need to compile and link with that.

Answer (score 4):

this works on ogre tutorials :

g++ -o otest *.cpp -I `pkg-config --libs --cflags OGRE OIS`